# No definition for GetFilesAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, storagefile, storagefolder

Whenever i try this code:

```
  foreach (StorageFile filesAsync in await folderFromPathAsync.GetFolderAsync(_selectedPlayList).GetFilesAsync())//Error here
        {
            this._fileNames.Add(filesAsync.Name.Substring(0, filesAsync.Name.LastIndexOf('.')));
            this.FilesListBox.Items.Add(filesAsync.Name.Substring(0, filesAsync.Name.LastIndexOf('.')));
            this._pathNames.Add(filesAsync.Path);
        }
```

The definition GetFilesAsync() doesnt exist for some weird reason.Is this a fault of me?
My full error message:

> `'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.StorageFolder>'` does not contain a definition for 'GetFilesAsync' and no extension method 'GetFilesAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly refrence?)

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `GetFilesAsync()` on the result of calling `GetFolderAsync()` - whereas you should be awaiting the result of `GetFolderAsync()` and then calling `GetFilesAsync()` on the result of the await. The return value from `GetFolderAsync()` isn't the folder - it's the asynchronous operation which is fetching the folder. (It's an `IAsyncOperation<StorageFolder>`, not a `StorageFolder`.)

For example:

```
var folder = await folderFromPathAsync.GetFolderAsync(_selectedPlayList);
foreach (var file in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I cant test it yet because my app is still in development it turns out without errors. I had to change the fileAsync.Name and that other to 'file' but that is not problem. thank you!

Comment: @myproducts: Well yes, I changed the variable name because `filesAsync` implied a) that it was a collection and b) that it was an async operation, neither of which was the case...